# java function returns multiple variables - call

Tags: java, function, reference, call

```
public static void delete(char[] qa, int[] aa, int[] bb) {
    if(front == -1 || front > rear) {
        System.out.println("Queue Underflow ");
        return;
    } else {
        //printf("Element deleted from queue is : %c\n", queue_array[front]);
        qa[0] = queueArray[front]; //to stoixeio pou deleted
        aa[0] = queueArray2[front2]; // x syntetagmenh del elem
        bb[0] = queueArray3[front3]; // y coordinate of del elem
        // *timegg=timeg;
        front = front + 1;
        front2 = front2 + 1;
        front3 = front3 + 1;

    }
}
```

I have created the above function as I want it to return these 3 values, qa, aa, bb. When I try to call it as`delete(qa, aa, bb);` I get:

```
method delete cannot applied to given types
required char[], int[], int[]
found char, int, int
reason actual and formal argument lists differ in lenght
```

What is the right and appropriate way to call this function? I thought what I wrote was right because everything in java is a reference.
I am a new to java, so maybe, I got the concepts totally wrong.

Comment: Note, `char` and `int` variables are NOT references in Java.

Comment: I even tried Character and Integer. Still wrong though?

Comment: Source doesn't match the error: `char[], int[], int[], int[]`. Yours has 3 args not 4, so it would seem to be picking up a different `delete`...

Comment: Create a class Result -- with 1 char , and 2 int  as propreties, create get/set and when you fetch values from your queues/Arrays, create instance of the new instance of "Result" with those vaules and return that instance, your return type in fn signature should be "Result" --- there are so many things wrong with it, I dont know where to begin..but what I said above should atleast make the code work and allow you to pass/access 3 variables through Result class -- forget the code, just put proper req. and we will help with more sensible code for it.

Answer (score 0):

The function is expecting 3 arrays as arguments.  You are calling the function with 3 primitive values.  Hence, the error message indicating that the actual type of the arguments does not match that which is expected.

If you have 3 arrays declared in a similar manner to the following (where 'a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3 are replaced with your actual values):

```
char qa[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
int aa[] = {1, 2, 3};
int bb[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

Then your method call will work:

```
delete(qa, aa, bb);
```

Note that the error message you have included in your post does not match the code provided since the error message shows that 4 arguments were expected where as the code provided has a function that requires 3 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing char[ ] and int[ ], you are passing char and int.

This will work.

```
char qa[] = new char[20];
int aa[] = new int[20];
int bb[] = new int[20];

delete(qa,aa,bb);
```

Answer (score -1):

why not just return an array of 3 values? I just don't see the point of passing in 3 arrays when you are only setting the first parameter anyway.

```
public static int[] delete()
{
   int[] arr = new int[3];

   <do whatever you want to arr>

   return arr;
}
```

This is allowed operation in java as it is memory managed.

Edit:

If you need generic types to be returned in Java:

```
public static ArrayList delete()
{
    ArrayList ret = new ArrayList();
    ret.Add('c');  //qa
    ret.Add(0);    //aa
    ret.Add(0);    //bb
    return ret;    
}
```

Comment: i  tried that as well, but later I had to convert objects to chars and other issues were caused to the rest of the program

Comment: Ah you can then use an ArrayList<Object> then if you need generic types perhaps?